# FileSaver.saveAs is not a function in angular 2

Tags: angular

code fileSaver in component.ts is

```
FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), 'exported.xlsx');
```

in systemjs.cinfigjs to package is

```
'file-saver': {
      format: 'global',
      main: 'FileSaver.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

and in meta is

```
'file-saver': 'npm:file-saver/FileSaver.js'
```

and in map is

```
'file-saver': 'node_modules/file-saver/FileSaver.js'
```

and in package.json  i install

```
"@types/file-saver": "0.0.1", 
"file-saver": "1.3.3"
```

Comment: try adding this in your component `import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver'`

Comment: thank you . i adding import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver' and the same error   FileSaver.saveAS is not a functioon and i try import * as saveAs from 'file-saver' and the same error saveas is not function

Comment: I am unable to reproduce it see the working [stackblitz](https://angular-q43eqd.stackblitz.io)

Comment: I'm sure you got an answer, but I believe the way you have it configured you just need to tell TS about it 

`declare function saveAs(data: Blob, fileName: string);`